# Is there an alternative to CyberGhost on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, vpn

When I used windows I used CyberGhost to mask my VPN. Well, they don't have a Linux ed, and I tried to install win ed with wine, but I cant for some reasons and now I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: Have you tried to set it up with openvpn. According to the website it should be supported https://support.cyberghostvpn.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/393/0/devices-that-support-cyberghost-vpn. Or perhaps "mask my vpn" means something different?

Comment: Go to: https://alternativeto.net/software/cyberghost/?platform=linux